# How do i make a pixel based game in java like Notch

Tags: java, 2d, pixel

I was wondering if any of you know any resources for learning this.
I saw Notches stream when he was making minicraft. It looks cool being able
to make this kind of game from scratch in java, but i have a hard time finding a place to start.

I know java and SWING. What i want to learn is working with BufferedImage, Sprite sheets and so on. I want to make the game from scratch with just plain java. So do any of you know a place to start?

Thanks

Comment: Start with installing Java and reading a book about programming? I mean, if you need a more detailed answer, you'll need a more specific question.

Comment: What you need is this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html JLayeredPane allows you to put as many JLabels (or other components) you wish (you can update them with SwingWorker class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). You can have many layers that you specify. It is really easy to use. SwingWorker creates a new thread where you can update your Swing components if you have animations (I'm thinking of background loops for example). I literally did a whole RPG-like game with the combination of these 2 features. Good luck

Comment: hey do you still searching for this? or you found some tutorials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Learn Game Programming

  - [Learn Programming](http://norvig.com/21-days.html)

    - Know a Language. Most any popular language will do. Notch uses Java, for what it's worth.
    - Understand data structures and algorithms
    - Understand basic software engineering principles
  - [Pick a book/tutorial to learn the basics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-are-some-good-resources-for-getting-a-beginner-started-in-developing-games)
  - [Start with a small project.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/854/what-are-good-games-to-earn-your-wings-with)

    - Minicraft is not a small project. But if you can make Pong, you can make Tetris with some work. If you can make Tetris, you can make Minicraft with a bit more effort.

Comment: I should've been more specific. I know java and i know some of SWING. The thing i dont know anything about it the BufferedImage and SpriteSheets and stuff like that. I am able to look up the refference on java classes but it doesnt give me an overview if you know what i mean.

Comment: Minecraft uses LWJGL. I dont' know if Minicraft uses that. They have a bunch of links on their wiki (http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Comment: Edit: I replied to this issue in a comment under your question. I moved the post there from here.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of steps to make if you want to reach the Minicraft level but I suggest you to learn how to use the Swing library (javax.Swing http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html). This allows you to open windows, design graphic user interfaces and draw lots of 2D (draw images, lines, rectangles and other shapes).

EDIT: I thought at first that you wanted to do something like minEcraft and not minIcraft so I added a 3d part below. You can skip the whole next paragraph! (Thanks to Kevin K for correcting me)

Once you'll be really comfortable with Swing (2D Graphics) you can go on with 3D and the Java openGL (JOGL http://java.net/projects/jogl/) library (you will have however to learn lots of information about 3D computation in computer science (vertices, etc.)). You can learn 3D basics by downloading Blender (a free 3D modelling software) and read some tutorials. Once you know how to compute 3D models and Blender (for example) you'll be able to import your 3D models in your Java program.

There are some frameworks you can work with but I suggest you to learn the basics before carrying on.

Yes there a lots of things to learn but with work and motivation you'll manage to do it!

Hope this helped.

Comment: Great answer...but the OP is asking about [Minicraft](https://s3.amazonaws.com/ld48/ld22/index.html), not Minecraft.  Minicraft is a 2D overhead game, so no 3D modeling is required :-)

Comment: Oops! My mistake. Well I guess the first part should do it. I'll edit my post a little bit ;-) Thanks for advising.

Comment: The confusion is understandable, I only noticed it because I had read about Minicraft recently, otherwise I probably would have missed it too